# Finding the distance of a point to an ellipse, wether its inside or outside of ellipse

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to find the distance of every pixel coordinate in an image to an ellipse.

To find the distance, I am using the following formula where p is the point of the pixel and h is the ellipse. x,y is the pixel coordinate, x(c),y(c) is the ellipse center, theta is the ellipse angle, alpha and beta is the major and minor axis of the ellipse respectively.

[image]

The code to determine the distance of every point to an ellipse is shown below. If the distance, D < 1 then it means that the point is inside the ellipse, in which case I make it grey. If D > 1 then it means that the point is outside the ellipse, in which case I leave it as it is. Below is also the output image I get. For some reason I think that my distance calculation is right, but I have a problem with my rotation. To me everything looks right, I cant see the problem. Please help. What I require is that the all pixels in the ellipse should be grey, but to me the grey area forms an ellipse but it seems as if I am going wrong with the rotation somewhere.

```
Mat distance2ellipse(Mat image, RotatedRect ellipse){
float distance = 2.0f;
float angle = ellipse.angle;
Point ellipse_center = ellipse.center;
float major_axis = ellipse.height;
    float minor_axis = ellipse.width;
Point pixel;
float a,b,c,d;

for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++) 
    {
        Scalar intensity = image.at<uchar>(Point(x, y));
        pixel.x=x;
        pixel.y=y;
        a = (cos(angle*PI/180)*(pixel.x-ellipse_center.x))/(major_axis);
        b = (sin(angle*PI/180)*(pixel.y-ellipse_center.y))/(minor_axis);
        c = (sin(angle*PI/180)*(pixel.x-ellipse_center.x))/(major_axis);
        d = (cos(angle*PI/180)*(pixel.y-ellipse_center.y))/(minor_axis);

        distance = sqrt(pow((a-b),2)+pow((c+d),2));

        if(distance<1)
        {
                image.at<uchar>(Point(x,y)) = 140;
        }
    }
}
return image;}
```

This is the output I get. The grey area should be in the pink ellipse.
[image]

Comment: What is the `angle` (theta) of your ellipse? Maybe you have confusion with degrees/radians?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are the declarations of `cos`, `sin`, and `PI`?

Comment: I'm still looking at your issue, but a quick first recommendation.  Square roots are expensive, especially when you're doing this many of them.  If you want to check to see if sqrt(X) < Y, check instead if X<Y*Y.

Comment: Drawing a filled ellipse is standard in graphics library.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @anatolyg The angle(theta) is in degrees. If I take the PI/180 (which converts to radians) away from the code, and only use cos(angle), which is in degrees, then I get the same result .

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks. PI is 3.14159265 and I am using math.h in c++ to get cos and sin.

Comment: @user30997 Thanks I will make a note of that.

Comment: @stark I am trying to fill an ellipse. What I am trying to do is to see whether a white pixel falls within the ellipse or not

Comment: If anyone has opencv, you can try the code. Here is a link to what I have so far, [link](http://www.cs.uwc.ac.za/~iachmed/geometric_tools.cpp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason I think that my distance calculation is right

It's not. The distance between some point and an ellipse is a transcendental equation. It cannot be solved by elementary techniques (which is what you did). You need to use root finding techniques.

Google is your friend. Here's a PDF file that provides an algorithm and provides code to implement it: http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePointEllipseEllipsoid.pdf .

**Edit**
Based on the comments below, my answer is orthogonal to what the OP wants.

lexma, the reason your ellipse doesn't look right is because you have the wrong equation for an ellipse that is rotated by some angle theta with respect to the x-axis. The problem of determining whether some point (x,y) is inside or outside the ellipse is fairly simple.

1. Convert your (x,y) coordinates to (u,v) to make the ellipse centered at the origin and with major axis along the u-axis, minor along the v-axis.

   u =  cos(θ)*(x-x<sub>c</sub>) + sin(θ)*(y-y<sub>c</sub>)
   v = -sin(θ)*(x-x<sub>c</sub>) + cos(θ)*(y-y<sub>c</sub>)
2. Compute the metric

   d<sup>2</sup> = (u/α)<sup>2</sup> + (v/β)<sup>2</sup>
3. Compare to one. The point is inside the ellipse if d<sup>2</sup> is less than one, on the ellipse if it is exactly one, and outside if it is greater than one.

Comment: It seems that *Finding the distance of a point to an ellipse* is not important at all for the OP; it's rather *wether its inside or outside of ellipse* that is needed

Comment: @David thanks for the link, I read that article before posting on this site. I did not understand much. I tried the code this time and I was getting big values, like between 200 and 800. I am not sure that it is giving me what I need.

Comment: @anatolyg Yes that is what I need. Given a white pixel in a binary image, I would like to find whether it is inside or outside of the ellipse. I am following this paper, **A.A. Argyros, M.I.A. Lourakis, “Real time Tracking of Multiple Skin-Colored Objects with a Possibly Moving Camera”, in proceedings of the European Conference on Computer Vision (ECCV’04), Springer-Verlag, vol. 3, pp. 368-379, May 11-14, 2004, Prague, Chech Republic**and need to do what he does. Here is a link to what I have so far, [link](http://www.cs.uwc.ac.za/~iachmed/geometric_tools.cpp).

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks so much!! That worked. I got a rotation but it was in the opposite direction and then for some reason I had to add 90 degrees to the angle to reflect the inverse of that rotation and that worked. Thank you once again! I cannot vote for this answer because I need 15 reputations, so someone else please vote for this. It helped!

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks for teaching me the ropes here. I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this is the problem but the line

```
distance = sqrt(pow((a-b),2)+pow((c+d),2));
```

does not look correct. The standard distance formula uses two deltas and not one.
This means that the line should look like this:

```
distance = sqrt(pow((a-b),2)+pow((c-d),2));
```

Notice that the second part is `c-d` instead of `c+d`

Comment: I tried changing as you suggested and I atleast got a rotation this time. It still isn't correct. I am getting these results, [image1](http://www.cs.uwc.ac.za/~iachmed/22.jpg) [image2](http://www.cs.uwc.ac.za/~iachmed/27.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution in [this paper](http://cdserv1.wbut.ac.in/81-8147-617-4/Linux/MagicSoftware/WildMagic2/Documentation/DistancePointToEllipse2.pdf) is definitely too expensive just to determine if a point lies inside, on or outside the ellipse, it might still help those folks who got here using google, mislead by the first part of the header. (like myself)